# Unity ScriptableObject Conversation Dialogue and Reading

Tags: unity, c#

I'm unsure as to how I would reference a scriptable object's variables within a struct from another class. I know I'd have to make a public `Conversation`, but I'm stuck understanding how I could access it's struct, and how I could access individual variables such as the `Position`, or `line` string array.

Is this method even viable or should I look at creating a different way of accomplishing a dialogue conversation scriptable object?

Thanks for any insights and help~

**My current code:**

````
[System.Serializable]
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Conversation", menuName = "Create/Conversation", order = 1)]

public class Conversation : ScriptableObject
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public struct LineData
    {
        public string[] line;
        public string[] option;

        public enum Position
        {
            BottomLeft,
            BottomCentre,
            BottomRight,
            MiddleLeft,
            MiddleCentre,
            MiddleRight,
            TopLeft,
            TopCentre,
            TopRight
        }

        public Position position;

        public enum TextSpeed
        {          
            Normal,
            Slow,
            Fast,
            UltraFast
        }

        public TextSpeed textSpeed;

    }
    public LineData[] Line;

}

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to be honest I didn't understand much about your codes but this is a right approach in many possible approaches:

any dialogue by a character can cause one or more dialogues from the same or other characters. so every dialogue can contain this model:

```
    class Dialogue
    {
public bool IsRoot;
public string Guid;// or any unique text
public string CharacterName;
public string DialogueText;
public List<string> ResultingDialoguesIds;
    }
```

you can make a ScriptableObject class that holds a list of this class(and also you can make a graph editor in unity to let designers make dialogues for you):

```
class LevelDialogues : ScriptableObject
{
public List<Dialogues> Dialogues;
}
```

when you want to start the dialogue in your game just query for dialogue that is signed as `IsRoot` and step by step generate Upcoming Dialogues. that is a simple way. maybe you can include some of your text formatting variable in Dialogue class.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me get closer to what I need~